# R keras "ValueError: Error when checking target", code works with other data

Tags: r, keras

I am trying to build a CNN for text classification in Rstudio Keras. I am new to this world of Neural Nets, so I am just looking at examples and see how I can learn from what others are doing. The model specification I use in the code below code is copied from this example I found [on the package GitHub.](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/keras/src/vignettes/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.R) I will refer to this code/example as "the example" further on.

When I run the example "as is" (i.e., with the data provided by the package authors), it runs fine. However, when I use my own data ( provided [here in rdata format](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlRdJrD0ErzX3FLbGtFQTFmb00/view?usp=sharing)), the model does not compile. It gets stuck on the following error message:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_22 to have shape (None, 10) but got array with shape (28686, 11)

To me, this means that `y_train` (i.e., the category labels) has the wrong shape. But, when I compare the dimensions and datatypes of the labels to those of the example, they have a similar format. Both are matrices in which the rows represent the training cases, and the cols are one-hot vectors representing the labels. The same goes for my embedding matrix (`embedding_matrix`) and my word sequences (`x_test, x_train`)

Does anyone have any thoughts on what may be going wrong here?

## Code

```
library(keras)
library(stringi)
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH <- 1000
MAX_NB_WORDS <- 20000
EMBEDDING_DIM <- 100

#Load my data
load("testdata.rdata")

#MARK start code copied from example
#without any changes

# load pre-trained word embeddings into an Embedding layer
# note that we set trainable = False so as to keep the embeddings fixed
num_words <- min(MAX_NB_WORDS, length(word_index))
 embedding_layer <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = num_words,
  output_dim = EMBEDDING_DIM,
  weights = list(embedding_matrix),
  input_length = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
  trainable = FALSE
)

cat('Training model\n')

# train a 1D convnet with global maxpooling
sequence_input <- layer_input(shape = list(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH), dtype='int32')

preds <- sequence_input %>%
  embedding_layer %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters = 128, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 5) %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters = 128, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 5) %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters = 128, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 35) %>% 
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>% 
  layer_dense(units = length(labels_index), activation = 'softmax')


model <- keras_model(sequence_input, preds)

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = 'rmsprop',
  metrics = c('acc')  
)

model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  batch_size = 128,
  epochs = 10,
  validation_data = list(x_val, y_val)
)
```

## Model summary:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                        Output Shape                    Param #     
================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)                (None, 1000)                    0           
________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)             (None, 1000, 100)               2000000     
________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)                   (None, 996, 128)                64128       
________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_4 (MaxPooling1D)      (None, 199, 128)                0           
________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_5 (Conv1D)                   (None, 195, 128)                82048       
________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_5 (MaxPooling1D)      (None, 39, 128)                 0           
________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_6 (Conv1D)                   (None, 35, 128)                 82048       
________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_6 (MaxPooling1D)      (None, 1, 128)                  0           
________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)                 (None, 128)                     0           
________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                     (None, 128)                     16512       
________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                     (None, 20)                      2580        
================================================================================
Total params: 2,247,316
Trainable params: 247,316
Non-trainable params: 2,000,000
________________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Glove data dimensionality, but your own `y_train` has indeed 11 columns and not 10:

```
load("testdata.rdata")
dim(y_train)
# [1] 28686    11
```

Moreover, your first column `V1` seems to be spurious, as it includes only zeros:

```
> summary(y_train) # shown only V1-V8
       V1          V2               V3                V4               V5                V6               V7                V8         
 Min.   :0   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.00000  
 Median :0   Median :0.0000   Median :0.00000   Median :0.0000   Median :0.00000   Median :0.0000   Median :0.00000   Median :0.00000  
 Mean   :0   Mean   :0.4336   Mean   :0.01928   Mean   :0.1167   Mean   :0.08143   Mean   :0.1171   Mean   :0.06041   Mean   :0.07227  
 3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:0.00000  
 Max.   :0   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.00000
```

So, if 10 is indeed the target dimensionality (your `labels_index` has indeed a length of 10), removing the (useless) first column from `y_train` should resolve the error:

```
y_train_new <- y_train[,2:11]
dim(y_train_new)
# [1] 28686    10
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue! (I didn't think of checking that myself)